# less: do not display "filename (END)" at the end of page

Tags: shell, less

I need `less` to display a file without any additional formatting characters.

I found the `--tilde` option, which got rid of the `~` characters.

Now I only need to get rid of the:

```
(END)
```

or

```
<filename> (END)
```

at the and of the page.

I am happy to recompile `less` , if somebody can suggest what needs to be changed in the sourcecode.

I am using `less` 487 on Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

You configure the prompt with -P, for instance, this will no longer show the filename or END (but still the :):

```
less -P ''
```

Comment: that does not remove the `(END)`. It makes it even worse. Not I get:  `zz.txt (file 1 of 3) (END) - Next: -P`

Comment: It works as described for me (version 551).  Maybe you need to set it to something explicit?